# Numpy: most efficient way of retrieving original columns in filtered array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's suppose we have a bidimensional array `arr1` with shape (10,4):

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.rand(10, 3)
np.random.seed(0)
b = np.random.randint(24, size=10)
b = b.reshape(len(b),1)
arr1 = np.hstack((a, b))
print(arr1)
```

`arr1` looks like this:

```
[[ 0.5488135   0.71518937  0.60276338 12.        ]
[ 0.54488318  0.4236548   0.64589411 15.        ]
[ 0.43758721  0.891773    0.96366276 21.        ]
[ 0.38344152  0.79172504  0.52889492  0.        ]
[ 0.56804456  0.92559664  0.07103606  3.        ]
[ 0.0871293   0.0202184   0.83261985  3.        ]
[ 0.77815675  0.87001215  0.97861834  7.        ]
[ 0.79915856  0.46147936  0.78052918  9.        ]
[ 0.11827443  0.63992102  0.14335329 19.        ]
[ 0.94466892  0.52184832  0.41466194 21.        ]]
```

Now, some external process is performed, so we lost the information in the last column and some rows are filtered:

```
arr2 = arr1[:,:3]
np.random.seed(0)
filter_arr = np.random.choice(10, size=6, replace=False)
arr2 = arr2[filter_arr]
print(arr2)
```

As a result, we got the following array `arr2`:

```
[[0.43758721 0.891773   0.96366276]
[0.11827443 0.63992102 0.14335329]
[0.56804456 0.92559664 0.07103606]
[0.94466892 0.52184832 0.41466194]
[0.54488318 0.4236548  0.64589411]
[0.77815675 0.87001215 0.97861834]]
```

The goal is **to efficiently check which rows according to the values from the three first columns remain in `arr2` and add the values from the fourth column of `arr1` to `arr2`**. Of course, the `filter_arr` in the previous step would be completely unknown.

The expected result would be this:

```
[[0.43758721 0.891773  0.96366276 21.        ]
[0.11827443 0.63992102 0.14335329 19.        ]
[0.56804456 0.92559664 0.07103606  3.        ]
[0.94466892 0.52184832 0.41466194 21.        ]
[0.54488318 0.4236548  0.64589411 15.        ]
[0.77815675 0.87001215 0.97861834  7.        ]]
```

Thx.

P.S. If you come up with a better title for this question, please, just let me know to change it in order to be more useful to other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can fit the broadcasting in memory, you can compare first 3 columns of `arr1` with `arr2` and then use [numpy.argmax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) after [numpy.all](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) (along the right axis) to retrieve the index of each row of `arr2` from `arr1`, finally use such indexes to get the last column of `arr1` and stack it with `arr2`.

As Jérôme Richard pointed out it is not safe to use `==` for comparison, you can use [numpy.isclose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) function and customize the tollerance to your need.

Regarding the eventuality of having `np.nan` values, `np.isclose` also accept the parameter `equal_nan` which by default is False but can be set to True so that `np.isclose(np.nan, np.nan, equal_nan=True)` returns `True` (if that's the behaviour you want to have).

```py
import numpy as np

idx = np.argmax(np.all(np.isclose(arr1[:, :3, None],arr2.T[None, :, :]), axis=1), axis=0)

filtered_last_col = arr1[idx, -1, None]

np.hstack([arr2, filtered_last_col])
array([[ 0.43758721,  0.891773  ,  0.96366276, 21.        ],
       [ 0.11827443,  0.63992102,  0.14335329, 19.        ],
       [ 0.56804456,  0.92559664,  0.07103606,  3.        ],
       [ 0.94466892,  0.52184832,  0.41466194, 21.        ],
       [ 0.54488318,  0.4236548 ,  0.64589411, 15.        ],
       [ 0.77815675,  0.87001215,  0.97861834,  7.        ]])
```

Comment: Note that `np.nan == np.nan` is `False` so it should works only without NaN. Moreover `arr2` should have exactly the same values (strict IEEE-754 comparison).

Comment: Yes you are totally correct, I didn't want to add numpy.isclose function, but it's worth mentioning. I will update the answer.